# Java MultiServer Chat

Tags: java, chat, nio

I would like to make a chat server in java, but I don't know if it's a good idea, because I can't understand what is the maximum of the users of which can handle...

I'm using NIO

Comment: NIO is very scalable. You could process tens of thousands of connections concurrently.

Comment: Looks like he's asking how scalable NIO is.

Comment: Here are 10 open sources chat servers. Even if you don't use them it may be worth looking at what they do and how they do it. http://www.java-sources.net/open-source/chat-servers

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your stance on third-party products, but Jabber is always an option and has been tried and tested by some of the industry's biggest sites. It's an XMPP-compliant server and can handle things like clustering, load-balancing, etc.

Answer (score 0):

A typical IO or NIO server can handle between 1K and 10K concurrent connections with Java 6.  NIO doesn't make as much difference to the maximum connections as it did with java 1.4. Assuming that the chat is light weight you should be able to reach 10K on a modest server.

If you just need 1K connections, I would use IO as this tends to be simpler to use and will do the job.